# Python: Results printing in the wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I am currently having a problem with my code. I have my results print first and then my words that are to print before that appear at the end.

```
 #   program that converst C to F in a table
def main():
    print('The given table converst Celsius to Farenheit.');
    print('Celsius  \t  Farenheit');

for C in range(1,21):
    F=(9/5)*C+32;
    print( C,"  {0:.1f}".format(F));

main()
```

Giving me the results

```
1   33.8
2   35.6
3   37.4
4   39.2
5   41.0
6   42.8
7   44.6
8   46.4
9   48.2
10   50.0
11   51.8
12   53.6
13   55.4
14   57.2
15   59.0
16   60.8
17   62.6
18   64.4
19   66.2
20   68.0

The given table convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.

Celsius       Fahrenheit
```

If you could help me solve this Problem that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Move the `for` loop into `main`.

Comment: Thank you. Seems I am that tired to have noticed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for loop is outside main definition first for loop is getting executed and then the main(). After moving for loop inside main definition it should work properly.

```
def main():
    print('The given table converst Celsius to Farenheit.');
    print('Celsius  \t  Farenheit');

    for C in range(1,21):
        F=(9/5)*C+32;
        print( C,"  {0:.1f}".format(F));

main()
```